# How to detect client side internet disconnection using Node.js

Tags: node.js, disconnect, node.js-stream

I am using node.js for game server .

Here is my server script

```
 var net = require('net');
 var http = require('http');

var host =  '192.168.1.77';
var portNum = 12345;//


  function policy() 
{
    var xml = '<?xml version="1.0"?>\n<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM' +
            '"http://www.macromedia.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">\n<cross-domain-policy>\n';

    xml += '<allow-access-from domain="*" to-ports="*"/>\n';
    xml += '</cross-domain-policy>\n\0' + "\0";
    return xml;
}



var server = net.createServer(function (stream) 
{
stream.setEncoding('utf8');

stream.on('data', function (data) { 

    if (data == '<policy-file-request/>\0') 
    {
        var x = policy();
        stream.write(x);
        var server_date = new Date();
        var serv_sec = server_date.getSeconds();
        return;
    }

    var comm = JSON.parse(data); 
    if (comm.action == "Join_Request"  && comm.gameId =="game1") // join request getting from client
    {
        var reply0 = new Object();
        reply0.message = "WaitRoom";
        stream.write(JSON.stringify(reply0) + "\0");   
     }
 });

stream.on('disconnect', function() 
{
    console.log("disconnect");
 });
stream.on('close', function ()  
{
console.log("Close");
}); 

 //stream.setNoDelay(true);
//stream.setKeepAlive(true, 200);
//stream.setTimeout(10, function(){
//  console.log('timeout');
//});
 stream.on('connect', function() {
 console.log('check 2', stream.connected);
 }   );
  stream.on('error', function () { 
  console.log("Error");
  }); // close function 

  });  // ===== create server end
  server.listen(portNum,host,{'heartbeat interval':1,  'heartbeat timeout' : 2}  );
```

===============================================================================================

Client side script

```
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Collections;
    using System;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Threading;
    using Boomlagoon.JSON;
    using JsonFx.Json;
    using System.Net.Sockets;

                      try 
                        {

                            tcpClient.Connect (host,portNum);
                            serverStream    =  tcpClient.GetStream ();
                            serverStream.Flush ();

                            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( new WaitCallback( ReceiveFromServer ) );



                            isConnectionActive = true;
                            isReadyToJoinRoom = true;
                            connected = 1;
                            disconnected =0;
                            c_global.isClientConnectOn = false;
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = false;

                        }
                        catch( ArgumentException l_exception )
                        {
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = true;
                            isConnectionActive = false;
                        }

                        catch( SocketException l_exception )
                        {
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = true;
                            isConnectionActive = false;
                        }

                        catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = true;
                            isConnectionActive = false;
                            connected = 0;
                            disconnected =1;

                        }


               public void ReceiveFromServer(object stateInfo) // Please call this function once
                {
                    print (" $$$$$$$$$$$ ReceiveFromServer  and isConnectionActive"+isConnectionActive);

                    while(isConnectionActive) // receive message continuously 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            byte [] inStream = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];

                            serverStream.Read (inStream,0,(int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            string returnData = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inStream);

                            print ("*^^^^^^^^^^* returnData"+returnData);
                            Decide_Action(returnData);


                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = true;
                        }


                    }

                }



           public void Decide_Action(string returnData)
           {
           try
           {

           var r_Msg = JSONObject.Parse(returnData); // recieved message r_Msg

           string msg = r_Msg.GetString("message") ;

           print ("Message = "+msg);

           switch(msg ) // check the action to do
           {
           case "Players_List":
           break;
           }

           }

           catch (Exception e)
           {
                            c_global.isClientDisconnectOn = true;
           }


           }
```

When game is close or quit from game , client disconnection detect  by server . That is "close" function and "error" function is calling that time.

But when internet disconnections from client system or device , that time "close" function or "error" function is not calling.

How to detect this kind of client disconnection

Client Net disconnection is not detecting by Node.js server .

Please help me , if anyone know the solution .

Answer (score 8):

**It isn't possible to differentiate a lost connection from an idle connection.**

At least, not directly without some modification...

TCP connections are designed to live even if no data is sent.  It is entirely possible to make a connection now, send nothing for 12 hours, and send data again later.  Should the server assume that the connection is no longer there?  By design, it will assume there is a connection unless there is a transmission failure.  That is, if data is sent and there is no ACK, the connection will eventually be closed and the appropriate events **will** fire.

**The solution is to use TCP keepalive.**  If you call `socket.setKeepAlive(true, 10000)`, you enable keepalive probe packets (effectively TCP packets with 0 bytes of data payload) to be sent on an idle socket 10 seconds after it becomes idle.  The remote system will ACK these packets.  If it does not, the connection is eventually assumed lost, and the events you're looking for will fire.

More information:

- http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay
- http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TCP-Keepalive-HOWTO/overview.html

Comment: @LijuThomas Post a packet capture so we can see what's happening.

Comment: Please help me , if anyone know the solution .

Comment: @LijuThomas It's not possible to help you without more information.  Post a packet capture like I suggested a couple weeks ago.

Comment: @LijuThomas Post a packet capture.  I don't know how to say it any other way.

Comment: Brad i already add stream.setKeepAlive(true, 200) in my script as you said . But its not working. I also post full my server script and client script with Question

Comment: @LijuThomas Obviously, you already did as I suggested.  You told me that several times.  What I told you, several times, is that I cannot help you without knowing what the real actual problem is, and for that we need a packet capture to actually see what is happening over the wire.  If you are unwilling or unable to use the tools you need to figure out what the real problem is, I am unable to help you.  Maybe someone else will sit down and recreate your entire scenario.  I would rather spend 30 seconds looking at the real information with real packets and help you with a full solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but since I am new to posting on stackoverflow I thought that I could practice on this question. So here goes:

A common solution is to have the client sending an explicit keep-alive message (application layer instead of a transport layer) to the server whenever the connection is idle. The server can then identify connection (and client health) problems by adding an idle timeout.

In short: You need an idle timer in the server to detect if the connection is lost. And you need an idle timer in the client to ensure that you send a keep-alive message whenever the connection is idle.

Server pseudo code:

```
const SERVER_TIMEOUT = 3000;
var idle;

function clientFailed() {
    // Client has failed or the connection is bad
}

function onClientConnect() {
    // Start connection health monitoring
    idle = setTimeout(clientFailed, SERVER_TIMEOUT);
}

function onClientSendOrReceive() {
    // make sure that the old timer does not trigger
    clearTimeout(idle);
    // Start a new idle timeout
    idle = setTimeout(clientFailed, SERVER_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Client side pseudo code:

```
const CLIENT_TIMEOUT = 2000;  // Should be less than the server timeout to account for normal network latency
var idle;

function sendKeepalive() {
    // Send keepalive message to server
}

function onConnectToServer() {
    // Start idle timer
    idle = setTimeout(sendKeepalive, CLIENT_TIMEOUT);
}

function onSendOrReceiveMessage() {
    // make sure that the old timer does not trigger
    clearTimeout(idle);
    // Start a new idle timeout
    idle = setTimeout(sendKeepalive, CLIENT_TIMEOUT);
}
```

Comment: There is no reason for this.  TCP keep-alive works just fine if it's actually used.  There is no reason for an application layer keep-alive when you control the server.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to probably handle the 'timeout' event, which is fired when there's too much inactivity. You can set how long you want that to be as well, though there's a reasonable default.

http://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_timeout

Comment: With the timeout event, there is no way to differentiate between an idle connection or a dead connection.

Answer (score 0):

There is (currently) no `disconnect` event defined to be emitted from [`net.Server`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_server) nor [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket). There is an [**`end`** event](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_event_end), fired from [`net.Socket`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_class_net_socket) when a `FIN` packet is received. When [keepalive](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_setkeepalive_enable_initialdelay) is used, `timeout` will be triggered if there is no `ACK` from the other end within the defined timeout (also note that the socket is **not** automatically closed in this case).